# React подключение компонентов

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Два js-файла находятся в одной папке "src", пользуюсь create-react-app. Почему я не могу отрендерить в другом файле, несмотря на то, что я импортировал, и путь указан верно? Когда рендрю в том же файле, где и находится компонент, всё работает. Но должно же рендриться и в других файлах, например, если я захочу вложить этот компонент в еще один компонент, находящийся в другом файле. Заранее спасибо.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom'

    function Art(){
        return(
            <h1>HI WORLD </h1>
        )
    }


export default Art
```

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom'
import Art from './index.js'



render(<Art/>,document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0):

ошибка здесь:

```
import Art from './index.js'
```

судя по всему, должно быть

```
import Art from './art.js'
```